# How to transfer data between server and client using Node and Angular?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an application built with Node.js, Express, Firebase 3.4.0, and Angular.js. On the server side in `server.js`, I initialize the app and then get the db reference to `users`:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var firebase = require("firebase");
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'views')));

// Firebase setup; this is where it messes up...
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "apiKey",
    authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "bucket.appspot.com"
});
var db = firebase.database().ref();
var users = db.child('users');

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('/views/index.html');
    // missing a statement to pass users to the view
});
```

Now, this `users` reference needs to be passed to `index.html`, preferably as an array, so that data will be manipulated and rendered in the view.

- *Is it possible to accomplish this given that I will be using Angular?*
- I understand that a templating language would be handy, but since both the server and the client sides speak the same language, *isn't there an easy and elegant way for them to just communicate data*?
- *What's a standard approach to such a problem?* The connection to the database **must** be opened on the server side, so there should be a way, in fact many ways, to transfer that data to the client side for further manipulation/decomposition

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, the index.html is delivered with no business data, just instanciating your AngularJS app on the client when the DOM is ready.

Then a dedicated Angular `service` for dealing with Users triggers.
This service asks the server for a JSON payload through the use of `$http` GET request.

On the server side you handle this request with a new route :

```
app.get('/users', function (res, req) {
   // send the users as JSON
})
```

When Angular receives a valid response, it then has the users and can choose to render them to HTML in a `controller`

This round trip can seems wasteful but it has the advantage to be autonomous, so you can reuse this dialog many times during the life of your application.

If you prefer to prepopulate the users on the `/` route. You need to use a server side templating engine so you can inject a `<script></script>` in your `index.html` containing some kind of global var with the initial state of your client app:

```
<script>window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = { users: … };</script>
```

This naming is arbitrary, it's just a convention of your choice, so Angular will know to check this first when it boots.